# How to match merged IP addresses with other array items

Tags: arrays, ruby, ip

I have three arrays, each one containing IP addresses:

```
a = ['157.154.64.71/32', '156.154.64.71/32','156.154.64.72/32', '156.154.64.73/32', '156.154.64.76/24']
b = ['155.154.64.71/32', '158.154.64.71/32','158.154.64.72/32', '158.154.64.73/32', '158.154.64.76/24']
c = ['159.154.64.71/32', '159.154.64.71/32','159.154.64.72/32', '159.154.64.73/32', '159.154.64.76/24']
```

And a fourth array that looks like this:

```
asn = [1,2,3]
```

I need to merge all the IP addresses with the gem NetAddr, so first I combine the three arrays, and then I merge the IP addresses.

```
require 'netaddr'

combined_arrays = a + b + c

merged_ips = NetAddr.merge(combined_arrays)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
puts merged_ips

155.154.64.71/32
156.154.64.0/24
157.154.64.71/32
158.154.64.0/24
159.154.64.0/24
```

And what I'm trying to do is to match the merged IPs from the arrays `a`, `b` and `c` with the items of the array `asn`.

So the final output should look like this:

```
155.154.64.71/32    2
156.154.64.0/24     1
157.154.64.71/32    1 
158.154.64.0/24     2
159.154.64.0/24     3
```

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
merged_ips.each do |ip|
  asn.each do |a|
    puts "#{ip}\t #{a}\n"
  end
end
```

Which gives the following output:

```
155.154.64.71/32     1
155.154.64.71/32     2
155.154.64.71/32     3
156.154.64.0/24  1
156.154.64.0/24  2
156.154.64.0/24  3
157.154.64.71/32     1
157.154.64.71/32     2
157.154.64.71/32     3
158.154.64.0/24  1
158.154.64.0/24  2
158.154.64.0/24  3
159.154.64.0/24  1
159.154.64.0/24  2
159.154.64.0/24  3
```

It repeats everything three times and I don't know how to match all the IP addresses with the correct items of the `asn` array.

Comment: You have two nested loops — you're going to get the cross product of the output. This is like a left join in SQL. What do 1,2 and 3 represent in your output?

Comment: Thank you @PaulSchreiber, the numbers 1, 2 and 3 represent private AS numbers for the IP addresses